# Standardized coefs in regression with a categorical predictor: there's something wrong

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, effect

From what I understood, standardized coefficients can be used as indices of effect size (with the possibility of using rules of thumb such as Cohen's 1988).  I also understood that standardized coefs are [expressed in terms of standard deviation](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Do_effect_size_heuristics_for_standardised_betas_exist), which makes them relatively close to a Cohen's d.

I also understood that one way of obtaining standardized coefs is to standardize the data beforehand. Another is to use the `std.coef` function from the `MuMIn` package.

These two methods are equivalent when using a linear predictor:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MuMIn) # For stds coefs


df <- iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>% 
  scale() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Species = iris$Species)


fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=df)
round(coef(fit), 2)
round(MuMIn::std.coef(fit, partial.sd = TRUE), 2)
```

In both cases, the coefficient is -0.12. I interpret it as follows: **for each increase of 1 standard deviation of Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length diminishes of 0.12 of its SD**.

And yet, these two methods give **different results** with a categorical predictor:

```
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=df)
round(coef(fit), 2)
round(MuMIn::std.coef(fit, partial.sd = TRUE), 2)
```

Which gives, for the effect of **versicolor** as compared to **setosa** (the intercept), 1.12 and 0.46.

Which should I believe to be able to say "the difference between **versicolor** and **setosa** is ... of Sepal.Length's SD"? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't standardize the implicit variables associated with `Species`, so those coefficients would not be standardized.

You could do so as follows:

```
dummies <- scale(contrasts(df$Species)[df$Species,])
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ dummies, data = df)
round(coef(fit), 2)
#      (Intercept) dummiesversicolor  dummiesvirginica 
#             0.00              0.53              0.90
```

This agrees with the results of `MuMIn::std.coef` if you set the `partial.sd` argument to `FALSE`.

Comment: Indeed it works! Thanks! So basically, the correct interpretation is `the difference between versicolor and setosa is 0.53 of Sepal.Length's SD`? So what does the non standardized coefs refer to then? Sorry for this follow up question, but I've never seen the use of `contrasts` and didn't quite understand how it works

Comment: I don't think standardizing dummy variables really makes statistical sense.  Before standardizing, the coef was the difference in means between the species; after standardizing, the same, but in weird units.  "`Sepal.Length`'s SD" isn't really a meaningful concept.

Comment: I understand. But if I wanted to use effect size interpretation rules of thumb (such as Cohen's d), should I use the standardized or the "dependent variable standardized only" results? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I am not familiar with those rules.  I'd suggest thinking about why you want to use them, then deciding which approach makes more sense based on those reasons.  You could ask on the stats.stackexchange.com site if you need help with the details.